# Is it possible to force generation of assets with Rails Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, less, asset-pipeline

Is there a way to force regeneration of assets every request when using the Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline?

I am having problems getting the system to pick up changes to files when using Less (less-rails) with a series of partials and mixin files. If I could just force the system to generation on each request I would be much more productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out.

The master.less file (as in the main less file that coordinates the other include files) needed to have the pipeline directives added to it.

So in my case, application.css contains:

```
/*
 *= require html5reset-1.6.1
 *= require master
*/
```

And master.css.less contains:

```
/*
 *= depend_on mixins
*/
@import "mixins";
```

Comment: You should emphasize that the important part is "depend_on" :)

Comment: What exactly does this do? Does it invalidate the cache on every request? What is happening in asset pipeline to accomplish the result you want?

Answer (score 50):

To force a complete regeneration of all assets use:

```
rake assets:clobber assets:precompile
```

Very handy when asset_sync isn't playing fair with you...

Answer (score 21):

You can reset the assets cache with

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Comment: Autmoatization would be preferable.

Comment: You'd have to put this command in a script set to run at whatever point you want to automate it into. I can't provide an automation suggestion without more information.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run your server in the `development` environment. I think you can also use something like `config.cache_classes = false` in your current environment's config file.

Comment: Was doing that, but turns out my issue was caused by slightly different problem. Thanks.